# Imacros Parsing String

Tags: java, javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, imacros

I was wondering if someone could show me how to extract part of string from a var in a Imacros java script.

```
WebPageNumber = "Code: ";
WebPageNumber += "TAB T=1" + NewLine;
WebPageNumber += "FRAME NAME="+"ext-comp-1006" + NewLine;
WebPageNumber += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=ID:00B70000007Wo0i_paginator_rpp_target EXTRACT=TXT" + NewLine;
WebPageNumber +=  "SET !CLIPBOARD {{!EXTRACT}}";
PlayMacro = iimPlay(WebPageNumber);
alert (iimGetLastExtract ());
```

My Result is 
1-75 of 75  Display 10  records per page    Display 25  records per page    Display 50  records per page    Display 100 records per page    Display 200 records per page

All I want to take from it is 1 & 75

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're already using the JS implementation of iMacros, wouldn't it be easier just to manipulate that information with JS?

```
    var extractString = iimGetLastExtract();
    var firstNumber = extractString.substring(0,1);
    var secondNumber = extractString.substring(2,2);
```

That's assuming that you'll always be looking for the first number and the second pair of numbers. You can also use regular expressions with the JavaScript String match() method, but 
that'll dump an array of values.